# Powers of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication, bsxfun

I have a square matrix A (nxn). I would like to create a series of k powers of this matrix into an nxnxk multidimensional matrix (Not element-wise but actual powers of the matrix), i.e.getting `[A^0 A^1 A^2..A^k]`. It's sort of a varied vandermonde for matrix case.

I am able to do it with loops but it is annoying and slow. I tried using bsxfun but no luck since I am probably missing something here.

Here is a simple loop that I did:

```
for j=1:1:100 
    final(:,:,j)=A^(j-1); 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform *cummulative version* of [`mpower`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) with a vector of `k` values.

Sadly, [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) hasn't evolved yet to handle such a case. So, the best I could suggest at this point would be having a running storage that accumulates the matrix-product at each iteration to be used at the next one.

Your original loop code looked something like this -

```
final = zeros([size(A),100]);
for j=1:1:100 
    final(:,:,j)=A^(j-1); 
end
```

So, with the suggestion, the modified loopy code would be -

```
final = zeros([size(A),100]);
matprod = A^0;
final(:,:,1) = matprod;
for j=2:1:100 
    matprod = A*matprod;
    final(:,:,j)= matprod;
end
```

Benchmarking -

```
%// Input
A = randi(9,200,200);

disp('---------- Original loop code -----------------')
tic
final = zeros([size(A),100]);
for j=1:1:100 
    final(:,:,j)=A^(j-1); 
end
toc

disp('---------- Modified loop code -----------------')
tic
final2 = zeros([size(A),100]);
matprod = A^0;
final2(:,:,1) = matprod;
for j=2:1:100 
    matprod = A*matprod;
    final2(:,:,j)= matprod;
end
toc
```

Runtimes -

```
---------- Original loop code -----------------
Elapsed time is 1.255266 seconds.
---------- Modified loop code -----------------
Elapsed time is 0.205227 seconds.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. This gives an element-wise power of the matrix. I am looking for the mpower of the matrix. that is A^k and not A.^k. I hope I am clear with my question. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. I'll try again to explain better. k is a vector of 0:1:m (m=100 for example). I would like to get the m powers of a matrix A (nxn). That is a multiarray of [A^0 A^1 A^2....A^m]. All in all m matrices. Or a nxnxm array.
I hope I am more clear now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @imtl Yes, I think it's clear now, thanks. Also, could you add any for-loop code that you might have tried to the question?

Comment: I've added the loop to the posted question. Sorry I am new to this website and unfamiliar with the format yet

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Well we are talking about beating matrix multiplication, not so easy to do. If `bsxfun` has to have vectorized `@mpower`, I think it would take more than just using BLAS. To start off, mathworks guys can do it at C-level loopy code to have the best possible implementation.

Comment: Oh boy, you used `j` as a variable... Do I have to link to Shai's brilliant post about that? ;)

Comment: @Adriaan Tell them I am immune to imaginary numbers and conjugate transposes ;)