# How to raise a matrix to a vector of powers in matlab without for loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a `2x2` matrix that I want to multiply by itself 10 times while storing the result after each multiplication. This can easily be done with a `for` loop but I would like to vectorize it an eliminate the `for` loop. My approach was to have my 2x2 matrix `a` and raise it to a vector `b` with elements `1:10`. The answer should be a `2x2x10` matrix that replicates typing

```
a^b(1)
a^b(2)
.
.
.
a^b(10)
```

To clarify I'm not doing this element wise I need actual matrix multiplication, and prefer not to use a `for` loop. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: you probably need to loop on this. Plus, a 2x2 matrix loop is definetly nothing to worry about. "Early optimization is the root of all evil"!

Comment: The answer**s** to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35034584/3372061) might be applicable to your problem. Also, you might be able to get other ideas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix). Finally, there's [this FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support)....

Comment: This can only be done with a loop, but it's very fast. Don't discount loops just because you were told they were in general terrible.  Loops can be quite fast if you **know** how to use them correctly. See the post linked as the duplicate for more details.

Comment: I'm not so much worried about speed here as I am learning alternative ways of doing operations in Matlab. I've done enough coding with for loops already and I'm trying to learn how to do things without them whether it's better or not.

Comment: I just noticed the question was reopened. Based on the description I woudl say it wasn't a duplicate to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547973/powers-of-a-matrix) because the duplicate question does not address that the exponents are `b(1)...b(n)` instead of `1:n`, but now a question which also ignores that is accepted.

Comment: b(1)..b(n) and 1:n are the same in the scenario I presented. The crux of the question was how to do the operation without a for loop.

Comment: For this particular problem I think a for loop is best fitting, but for calculating a matrix of high powers I would say there are other ways. For example this [maths stackexchange link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256509/how-to-calculate-matrix-raised-to-a-high-power)

Comment: The this answer offers the best possible performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32548019/2732801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code for you. I use the `cellfun` to do this and I have comments after each line of the code. It can compute and store from fisrt - nth order of the self-multiplication of an arbitrary matrix `m`. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

```
function m_powerCell = power_store(m, n) %m is your input matrix, n is the highest power you want to reach

  n_mat = [1:n]; %set a vector for indexing each power result in cell

  n_cell = mat2cell(n_mat,1,ones(1,n)); %set a cell for each of the power

  m_powerCell = cellfun(@(x)power(m, x), n_cell, 'uni', 0);  %compute the power of the matrix

end

%this code will return a cell to you, each element is a matrix, you can
%read each of the matrix by m_powerCell{x}, x represents the xth order
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling that it could be done via cells and cellfun but I'm still pretty new to using cells.

Comment: The n_cell part is what I was missing, I was trying to use power vector straight into cellfun.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in this code, a simple for loop `for ix=1:n
    M(:,:,ix)=a^ix;
end` runs faster and is easier to understand. Using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547973/powers-of-a-matrix) you get an even better performance. `cellfun` is just a wrapper for a loop, it does not vectorize.